# Apparent invocation of macro not resolved in sas filename pipe

Tags: linux, sas, pipe, sas-macro

I am using the following SAS code to find all files and their sizes under the directory `&directory.`

```
filename tmp pipe "find &directory. -type f -printf '%p %s\n'";
data all_files;
  infile tmp;
  length file_path $255. size 8.;
  input file_path size;
run;
```

Though the output data `tmp` is what I want, the code will give me warning.

> WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro S not resolved.

I have tried adding an extra '%' before '%', i.e.

```
filename tmp pipe "find &directory. -type f -printf '%%p %%s\n'"
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I get rid of the warning? Thank you.

---

I have also tried `%str` and `%nrstr`,

```
filename tmp pipe %str("find &directory. -type f -printf '%p %s\n'");
filename tmp pipe %nrstr("find &directory. -type f -printf '%p %s\n'");
filename tmp pipe %str("find &directory. -type f -printf '%%p %%s\n'");
filename tmp pipe %nrstr("find &directory. -type f -printf '%%p %%s\n'");
filename tmp pipe "find &directory. -type f -printf '%str(%%)p %str(%%)s\n'");
filename tmp pipe "find &directory. -type f -printf '%nrstr(%%)p %nrstr(%%)s\n'");
```

None of them solved the problem.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in `%str()` or `%nrstr()`? https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n09tblrxldh8k0n1kt6dkj3xlxug.htm

Comment: or `%str(%%)p %str(%%s)`

Comment: @Reeza tried, but they are either not working or giving the same warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro processor will look for macro triggers `&` and `%` inside of strings enclosed in double quotes, but not those enclosed in single quotes.  You can use the `quote()` function to enclose the string in single quotes.

```
%let cmd=find &directory/ -type f -printf '%s %p\n' ;
filename tmp pipe %sysfunc(quote(&cmd,%str(%')));
```

Or you can just use SAS code and avoid letting the macro processor get involved.

Instead of making a FILENAME statement you could use a datastep to call the `FILENAME()` function.

```
data _null_;
  rc=filename('TMP'
     ,catx(' ',"find &directory/ -type f -printf",quote('%s %p\n',"'"))
     ,'PIPE');
  put rc= ;
run;
data all_files;
  infile tmp truncover;
  input size file_path $255. ;
run;
```

Or you could not create a fileref at all and instead just use the `FILEVAR=` option on the `INFILE` statement to pass in the command.

```
data all_files;
  length cmd $200;
  cmd = catx(' ',"find &directory/ -type f -printf",quote('%s %p\n',"'"));
  infile tmp pipe filevar=cmd truncover;
  input size file_path $255. ;
run;
```

**Note:** reversing the order of the size and path in the printf string will avoid issues parsing the results when there are filenames that have embedded spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
%macro get_filenames(location);
filename _dir_ "%bquote(&location.)";
data filenames(keep=memname);
handle=dopen( '_dir_' );
if handle > 0 then do;
count=dnum(handle);
do i=1 to count;
memname=dread(handle,i);
output filenames;
end;
end;
rc=dclose(handle);
run;
filename _dir_ clear;
%mend;
%get_filenames(path)
```